# How to implement security correctly in firebase?I

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication

I'm struggling to understand security in firebase and how to implement it correctly

I have this (the default) for development

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

the docs say `These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your app, read and write access to your database`

but how? I've built private routing (with react-router) into my app so unless a user is logged in they cant access all the private routes. any that include submitting/pulling data are behind private routes

so my question is, why do I need to secure the data with database rules? considering users won't be able to add/modify data unless they are logged in. (they can only log in with google in my app) so they would need to know another user google password to access my app. at which point, I can't defend against that anyway. and obviously each user has a UID but that is secured within the auth DB in firebase so I'm struggling to see what the benefit of this is?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and even how it works?

Answer (score 0):

If read/write is set to true for everything, then your database can be accessed by anyone who downloads the firebase npm package and knows how to rub a few lines of javascript together.

You may have written a website which asks for login before running the code which accesses the database, but other people can write their own websites or scripts that don't have this check. The security must be enforced on the server side, and that's done using the firebase security rules.

Comment: ok thanks, makes sense. but not sure why when I implement the second rules posted then my app doesn't retrieve the data?

Comment: I don't know. Are you getting an error message? What's the code that's attempting to retrieve the data? Feel free to update your question.

Comment: I'm hitting api gateway which triggers a lambda. my endpoint is: `https://api-gate-way-id.amazonaws.com/data/get-data?userId=${action.id}` so I'm passing the ID in this instance. no error messages although I just see my request failed in the network tab

Comment: im just trying to read like this inside my lambda: `let readData = firebaseApp.database().ref(users/${userID}/data)`. do I need to send something else to allow the user to read it?